# Xbox network connection wont stop testing

Tags: xbox-360

I've been trying to connect my Xbox 360 to my home network to update a game but it is just continually testing the network connection? I tried unplugging and plugging it back in after 5 minutes and stopping and restarting test but no dice. suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

First, try to power cycle your console. The instructions are [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/xbox/forum/all/how-to-powercycle-hard-restart-your-xbox/309a59c4-c466-4f67-9f18-1bed07d76fc7). But you can follow these steps:
 1. Hold down the console power button for 10 seconds
 2. Press console power button (to turn it back on, your cache and some settings will now be cleared)

Optionally:
 1. Settings -> System Settings -> Storage -> Clear System Cache

I would also try to unplug/ power off your router/ modem (both if separate). Keep it unplugged for 30 seconds or so before powering back up.